# Reusing same ImageView multiple times in the same scene on JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

I'm trying to build a Twitter-style ListView, and I couldn't reuse the same ImageView multiple times in the same list. Loading multiple copies seem to be wasteful and causes scrolling to slow down due to UI Virtualization. Are there any workarounds?

```
public class TwitterCell extends ListCell<Object> {

private static HashMap<String, ImageView> images = new HashMap<String, ImageView>();

@Override
protected void updateItem(Object tweet, boolean empty) {
  super.updateItem(tweet, empty);
  Tweet t = (Tweet) tweet;
  if (t != null) {
    String message = t.getMessage();
    setText(message);
    String imageUrl = t.getImageUrl();
    if (!images.containsKey(imageUrl)) {
      images.put(imageUrl, new ImageView(imageUrl));
    }
    setGraphic(images.get(imageUrl));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A scenegraph cannot contain the same `Node` twice in JavaFX, and there is no way of cloning nodes (as far as I know).

A workaround would perhaps be to make your map a `HashMap` store `Image` instead of `ImageView`, and change the last row to

```
setGraphic(new ImageView(images.get(imageUrl)));
```

This way you'll at least cache the loading of the actual `Image`, which should really be the heavy lifting part.

Answer (score 0):

Caching images is good way.

Also You can load images in background, it greatly improve performance.

```
public Image getImage(String path, boolean backload) {
   image = imageCache.get(path);
   if (image == null) {
      image = new Image(path, backload);
      imageCache.put(path, image);
   }
   return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
ImageView image = ...
ImageView src   = ...
image.setImage(src.getImage());
```

Comment: Try to explain the code you post so that people can learn from it

Comment: When you have a source image (src) that you want to duplicate elsewhere then you have to create a new image and borrow the _image_ property form the source (src). `ImageView` `newImage` `=` `new` `ImageView();` `newImage.setImage(src.getImage());`

Comment: Please use the edit link above instead of commenting :-) Thanks