# JavaFX setGraphic() not displaying icon in MenuItem

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, icons

I need an icon for my `MenuItem`'s.

This is like a "worker class" to get the `ImageView` of the icon :

```
public class IconFactory {

private static ImageView HLP_BOOK_JFX;

public enum ICONS {
    BASCET_REMOVE, BASCET_PUT, SAVE, OPEN, ARROW_RIGHT, ARROW_LEFT, ARROW_UP, ARROW_DOWN, CLOCK, ANALOG_SIGNAL, DIGITAL_SIGNAL, REFRESH, GREEN_PLUS, NETWORK, OK, CANCEL, RIGHT_NAV2, LEFT_NAV2, PLAY, PAUSE, LIST_ADD, PAGE_FIND, SET_PARAM, DOWNLOAD, UPLOAD, LOG_FILE, WARNING, INFO, LOG_DIAG, DATA_TRANS, TREE, FILTER, SEARCH, PARAM, ERASE, RESETDEF, RESETDEF2, DEBUG_BUG, INTERNATIONAL, CLOSE, HLP_BOOK
}

public static ImageView getImage(ICONS en) {
    switch (en) {
        case HLP_BOOK:
            if (HLP_BOOK_JFX == null)
                HLP_BOOK_JFX = new ImageView(new Image(IconFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("help_book.png")));
            return HLP_BOOK_JFX;
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I use `myMenuItem.setGraphic(IconFactory.getImage(ICONS.HLP_BOOK))` for a **single** menu item **it works perfectly.**

**But then, when I want to generate two menus in a loop and set the same graphic, one `MenuItem` has no icon displayed.** (the first one in loop in the code below).

---

**My code:**

```
while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {

    // that will do 2 loops, do not care about how

    MenuItem subMenuHelp = new MenuItem("MenuItem");
    subMenuHelp.setGraphic(IconFactory.getImage(ICONS.HLP_BOOK));
    subMenuHelp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // do not care
                openHelpFile(link);
            }
    });
        System.out.println(((ImageView) subMenuHelp.getGraphic()).toString());
        myMenu.getItems().add(subMenuHelp);
}
```

As you can see, I added a `System.out.println` to see if a graphic was set for the current item. 
Result in console : both lines (MenuItem) with the same `ImageView`:

```
ImageView@79814766[styleClass=image-view]
ImageView@79814766[styleClass=image-view]
```

---

I did exactly the same in Swing (but with `Icons` and `.setIcons()` function)  and it worked very well. I've also looked for a "repaint" function to force displaying but no way.

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the same `Node` cannot be attached to the scene-graph multiple times and - as you even state - you are adding the same `ImageView` object.

From the [documentation of Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html):

> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region,
>   etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the
>   root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from
>   its former parent.

The solution is to modify `getImage` method of `IconFactory` to return a new `ImageView` instance on each call or to return `Image` instances rather than `ImageView` instances (the second one fits better to the name "IconFactory" I think).

You could store the `Image` instance instead of storing the `ImageView` to avoid re-loading the `Image` itself. You could check this question as reference: [Reusing same ImageView multiple times in the same scene on JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175022/reusing-same-imageview-multiple-times-in-the-same-scene-on-javafx)

*A possible update on `IconFactory`:*

```
public class IconFactory {

    private static HashMap<ICON, Image> images = new HashMap<ICON, Image>();

    public enum ICON {
        BASCET_REMOVE, BASCET_PUT, SAVE, OPEN, ARROW_RIGHT, ARROW_LEFT, ARROW_UP, ARROW_DOWN, CLOCK, ANALOG_SIGNAL, DIGITAL_SIGNAL, REFRESH, GREEN_PLUS, NETWORK, OK, CANCEL, RIGHT_NAV2, LEFT_NAV2, PLAY, PAUSE, LIST_ADD, PAGE_FIND, SET_PARAM, DOWNLOAD, UPLOAD, LOG_FILE, WARNING, INFO, LOG_DIAG, DATA_TRANS, TREE, FILTER, SEARCH, PARAM, ERASE, RESETDEF, RESETDEF2, DEBUG_BUG, INTERNATIONAL, CLOSE, HLP_BOOK
    }

    public static Image getImage(ICON en) {

        if (!images.containsKey(en)) {
            switch (en) {
            case HLP_BOOK:
                images.put(en, new Image(IconFactory.class.getResourceAsStream("help_book.png"))); break;
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
        return images.get(en);
    }
}
```

*Usage after the update:*

```
subMenuHelp.setGraphic(new ImageView(IconFactory.getImage(ICONS.HLP_BOOK)));
```

Comment: Oh so! thank you very much for your quick help. 

So I updated my IconFactory to return new ImageView at each call and it works perfectly.